# Python + OpenCV + imencode

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror

I have this script part:

```
image = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)                
cv2.putText(image,"Hello World!", (10,10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 255)
cv2.imwrite("/temp/image.jpg", image)
```

This works fine.

But I want to encode the edited image with imencode():

```
result, img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image, [1, 90])
```

And I get this error message:
result, encimg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image,  [1, 90])

*TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable*

Anyone know what's wrong with this?

Comment: Instead of excerpting the part of the error you *think* is relevant to us, please [edit] your question to include the **full** traceback

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an older opencv version, where the signature was 
result=imencode(ext, img, outBuffer)

Hopefully you can get a newer opencv library version.

See http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Bug-Python-cv2-imencode-td7185380.html for a similar report.